# All table rows change color on iOS

Tags: html, css

I styled my `Table` with different colors on every row (odd/even), but when hovering over one row, it should change it's color. It works well on PC but for some reason it changes every of the rows' colors to the same color in my iPhone when clicking one of the rows. This is an example using the same `CSS` I used.

```css
.tablestyle tr
{
    background: #b8d1f3;
}

.tablestyle tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background: #b8d1f3;
}

.tablestyle tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background: #dae5f4;
}

.tablestyle tr:hover
{
    background: #7CAAE9;
}

.tablestyle tr:first-of-type
{
    background: #2470D5;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablestyle" border="1" style="width:70%">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
</table>
```

I couldn't find anything wrong with this code, but why then it changes every of the rows' colors?

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't text selection? Because I can't seem to trigger `:hover` at all on iOS.

Comment: `:hover` works in my iPhone, but only when touching the row. For some reason, it colors every row with the same color.